# Problem with Colour Fill in Closed Path in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, fill

I am creating a logo and have drawn a motif with the pen tool and - as far as I'm aware - the path is closed as I'm able to fill it with colour.

However, on closer inspection, the fill colour is not sticking to the path as the boundary, in fact it's either filling outside the path or within it.

The motif was initially a little crude so I used the smooth tool and I wonder if this has caused any issues. In one area it looks like the fill has glitched and there are little lines of white appearing along the path.

Does anyone know why this might be happening and how I can fix it? I have tried removing the fill and then replacing, and also tried some pathfinder options - uniting & merging but no luck.

[image]

Comment: Try this. Do ***View > CPU Preview*** to switch off GPU rendering. If that fixes the problem, then it must be a GPU rendering glitch. For a more permanent fix, try updating your graphics card driver.

Comment: I'm assuming this is Illustrator? I can't think of any Smooth Tool or Pathfinder elsewhere. The "little white lines" would be a GPU issue as Billy suggests.. the fill not remaining within the path could be an **Align to Pixel Grid** issue.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention it was in Illustrator! That’s great thank you both for your help. I will try this tonight and update you.

Comment: Thank you guys. That advice worked a charm!